# How can I access onBindViewHolder items of a given adapter in another class adapter?

Tags: java, kotlin, android-recyclerview, global-variables, adapter

I'd like to access DayOfWeek in onBindViewHolder below in the next class, the ChildViewHolder so I can use it in the if statement as shown in the ChildRecyclerAdapter.

```
class ParentRecyclerAdapter(private var parentArrayList: ArrayList<String>?, private var context: Context, private var mTableFeed: TableFeedJava?
) :  RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentRecyclerAdapter.ParentViewHolder>() {


 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.DayOfWeek.text = this.parentArrayList!![position]
}
 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return parentArrayList!!.size
    }

    inner class ParentViewHolder (itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    {
        internal var DayOfWeek: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayOfWeek)
        internal var ChildRV: RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ChildRecycler)
}
```

This is the ChildRecyclerAdapter. I need DayOfWeek from Parent to use it in this class as

```
class ChildRecyclerAdapter(
    private var time: ArrayList<String>,
    var context: Context,
    private val parentArrayList: ArrayList<String>? = null


) :
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChildViewHolder, position: Int) {

                holder.timeOfDay.text = time[position]
                mTableFeed = TableFeedJava(context,mLectures)
                holder.childofChildRV.adapter = mTableFeed

//THIS IS WHERE I PLAN ON USING THE IMPORTED 'DayOfWeek' AS SEEN ON 'holder.timeOfDay.text'
               for (i in mTimeSpinner!!.indices){
                   if(holder.timeOfDay.text == mTimeSpinner!![i]){
                       holder.childofChildRV.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                   }else{
                       holder.childofChildRV.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                   }
               }
```

I know the code is in Kotlin but I can accept Java answers too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply pass an object in

```
private var time: ArrayList<YourClass>
```

instead of

```
private var time: ArrayList<String>
```

Seems to me to be the simplest solution